# Master-Detail view - SAPUI5 : Passing argument from Master to Detail controller

Tags: data-binding, sapui5

In Master controller, on selection of item in the list, I am calling the detail view and binding the model data.

Master Controller:

```
 itemSelected: function(result)(
        var app =  sap.ui.getCore().byId("appId");
        var list = sap.ui.getCore().byId("mainListId");
        var selectedItem = list.getSelectedItem();
        var selectedPath = selectedItem.oBindingContexts.MainList.sPath;
        var Item = sap.ui.getCore().getModel("MainList").getProperty(selectedPath);
        var endPoint = Item.Endpoint;
        console.log(endPoint);
        var oModel =new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(Item);

        sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel,'DetailItem');
        app.toDetail('idDetail','slide')
    },
```

Detail View:
I am able to bind the model data here in oTable.

```
oTable.bindRows("DetailItem>/");
```

1.How store the model data in a variable? (tried: sap.ui.core().getModel(modelname).getData() and similar others. This gives undefined, as it gets read even before the ItemSelected function in the Master controller is called.)

2. How to bind/get the model data into Detail controller ***after*** the itemSelected function is called?

Thanks!

Comment: https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.SplitContainer/methods
`toDetail('idDetail', 'slide', { someData: 'foo' })`

Comment: I strongly suggest doing the tutorials **Walktthrough** and **Navigation & Routing**: https://openui5beta.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/8b49fc198bf04b2d9800fc37fecbb218.html Seems like you are missing core concepts

Answer (score 0):

You can set the model to i.e. a view by using the following statement: 
this.getView().setModel(oModel, "modelID");